# Difference between Ethereum Consortium Blockchain template and STRATO Blockchain Individual Instance template in Azure

Tags: private-blockchain, microsoft-azure

I have recently started analysing Blockchain as a service and found it's very interesting. But, I am not able to interconnect these information's.

What is difference between **Ethereum Consortium Blockchain template** and **STRATO Blockchain Individual Instance template**?  What are the use cases for above templates?

So, Kindly help me to fill the gap.

Comment: I would kindly ask to split this question to three different questions, as this question is three different questions and this is the policy of StackExchange forum. Edit this question, remove two other questions and recreate them as standalone.

Comment: updated the question as per policy